# Alternative to s3cmd for syncing between local folder and Amazon s3 with encryption capability

Tags: encryption, ubuntu, synchronization, amazon-s3

Currently I am writing something like this in ubuntu to sync my photos to Amazon s3, as an archive:

```
cd /media/PHOTO/Pictures
s3cmd sync --dry-run --delete-removed ./ s3://bob.photos/Pictures/ > ~/Desktop/output.txt
```

Since I think my photos are not very sensitive data, so I just leave the encryption issue aside. But as gmail start to have some issue to wiping out all of the user's email, so I am thinking of use s3 as my alternative backup for gmail also.

I am using getmail for retrieving mails from gmail, and I planned to upload it to s3 also, but the encryption issue arise again, this time I need to encrypt them all.

I have seen the s3cmd manual, and it said something like I need to upload every files again for every time, which I think it will be a waste of money.

Can anyone suggest an alternative of s3cmd, with encryption capability, preferably on the fly (i.e. it encrypts when upload, and decrypts when download but itself), manipulation by command is fine to me. And if it is OK, I will use it for my photos also.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try [Rclone](https://rclone.org/) . This Allow you to do a Rsync - like operations. It can do multipart upload and can create upload in parrallel.. 
It also has Fuse capabilties... 
I use it for my website.

Create Bucket :

```
 rclone mkdir CONFIGURATIONFORCLOUD:my-bucket-in-the-cloud
```

Dry Run :

```
rclone   --dry-run  --verbose --transfers=2 -q --checkers=1 copy  CONFIGURATIONFORCLOUD:my-bucket-in-the-cloud  /LOCALDIRECTORYFORFILETOBEUPLOADED --log-file /var/log/rclonelog/rclone.log
```

Start a sync between local folder and Remote Bucket :

```
rclone sync /LOCALDIRECTORYFORFILETOBEUPLOADED CONFIGURATIONFORCLOUD:my-bucket-in-the-cloud  --retries 4 --verbose --transfers=4 --log-file /var/log/rclonelog/rclone.log
```

As you can see you can LOG , Choose the number of concurrent sessions and do retries.

Rclone create a file profil per linux users, so If you have several users with different buckest level access, this can be used to match the rights

Comment: To add some comments : You can multipart upload, Do a Dry run, add loggings etc..

Answer (score 0):

Just off-hand I would say the solution is download your emails, run gpg, save the output, then upload to s3 via s3cmd with sync. As long as you only download new email and gpg those you won't be uploading files repeatedly. Basically something like this:

```
getmail
gpg -e 
s3cmd sync
```

I'm obviously just prototyping here (i've never tried to do what you want) but idea should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try s4cmd. It is the best and fastest alternative to s3cmd. I can upload about 30 GB over night.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39519397/issues-with-s4cmd